# How do I check for error code from os.system?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python system call that takes a while to finish.

```
os.system("call_that_takes_quite_some_time")
```

In the meanwhile I want to keep throwing a message that says "waiting..." every now and then till the os.system returns 0 or an error.
/
How do I do this? Is there something in python that I can "listen" to in a while loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`os.system` waits till your command execution is complete.
use `subprocess.Popen` you can check output or error. Popen gives handle and you can check return code using wait to find out command is successful/failure. For ex:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
while proc.poll() is None:
      print proc.stdout.readline() #give output from your execution/your own message
 self.commandResult = proc.wait() #catch return code
```

Comment: Where can you print the "waiting..." message?

Comment: You can do print "waiting" instead of print proc.stdout.readline(). I have corrected indentation in my answer...pls take latest...

Comment: How often does `poll` returns? If it returns immediately then this will print too many messages, if it blocks then this won't print anything.

Comment: You cannot control the timing with poll. Ideally, it supposed meant to get output from your running command and print to file/stdout...

Comment: But OP wants to print "Waiting..." messages every now and then while waiting for the process to complete.

Comment: If he want to control timing, can either use time module with subprocess or use threading module with Timer function...

Comment: There's no need for the threading or time modules. Use `retcode = proc.wait(timeout)` in a loop; handle `TimeoutExpired` by printing 'Waiting...'. Also, I don't think the OP cares about piping `stdout` or `stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

```
import os
import time
import threading

def waiter():
    waiter.finished = False
    while not waiter.finished:
        print 'Waiting...'
        time.sleep(1)
os_thread = threading.Thread(target=waiter)
os_thread.daemon = True
os_thread.start()
return_value = os.system('sleep 4.9')
return_value >>= 8  # The return code is specified in the second byte
waiter.finished = True
time.sleep(3)
print 'The return value is', return_value
```

This will print "Waiting..." message every 1 second, and it stops after `waiter.finished` is set to `True` (in this case there will be 5 "Waiting..." messages)

But `os.system` is not recommended. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) recommends using `subprocess` module.